# How to fix object orientation in three.js when animating from an imported fbx-file?

Tags: animation, three.js, orientation

ThreeJS wrong objects orientation when play animation from fbx

Hi 2 all!
When importing a fbx-file in threejs encountered a problem with incorrect orientation of some models with animation.
[Objects with correct orientation with no animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iX7Tf.png)
[Objects with incorrect orientation with animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcvrY.png)

How to correct objects orientation with animation?